# How to rat proof space around dryer vent hole (inside home)?

Tags: mice

This is 3rd floor condominium,

Dryer vent goes up and opens on the roof.

There is around 4 to 5" extra space around dryer vent in my wall, my neighbor reported rat in their house. I want to seal this space and make it rat proof.

My questions.

1. what can I use to cover extra space ? Drywall patch ?
2. to make it rat proof, I can stuff it with steel wool but there is going to be lot of cavity inside wall, how can I ensure that Steel wool is packed and dense around the opening and not loose because of lot of space inside wall.

Duct goes up towards roof (yellow arrow)
Red arrows shows space I want to seal so rats can’t come in.

[image]

Comment: Post a few pictures, that will help us help you.

Comment: @Gil - I posted picture

Comment: Rats can chew through just about anything including drywall.  I would try to figure out how to get rid of the rats. Closing the hole would tend to discourage them from going through that wall. From what I can see you may have to remove some drywall then add a new piece some from stud to stud to patch it properly.

Comment: The duct inside the cavity is rigid, not flex, right?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Yes, duct inside wall is rigid.

Answer (score 3):

I would adhere (probably caulk (rather than an epoxy, or some such) to allow it be removed more easily, at a later time) a tight fitting (around the duct) piece of sheet metal (or Al or something metal and thin) to the ceiling. I would then caulk around the duct and edges (to minimize traveling "smells" that attract rodents). You could also use use inserts and screws to fasten the sheet metal to the ceiling.

In my experience, steel wool is good when the hole's small or has a backer to limit the amount steel wool volume needed. (I'd also caulk over it.) Another tip - use "copper wool" when there's a chance of the steel wool rusting and staining the surroundings.

Comment: There are copper mesh products sold for excluding rodents.

Comment: **steel wool** +1